# Get the first day of a month in java FOR a local calendar

Tags: java, android, calendar, local

I know how to do it for the standard Gregorian calendar but I want it for a local calendar for my community. The plan is to make a calendar app for android.

I have this code for the Gregorian calendar but can't figure out the algorithm behind it.

```
public static int day(int M, int D, int Y) {
    int y = Y - (14 - M) / 12;
    int x = y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400;
    int m = M + 12 * ((14 - M) / 12) - 2;
    int d = (D + x + (31*m)/12) % 7;
    return d;
}
```

Also, let me know if this is the correct procedure for a calendar app. I'll appreciate if you can suggest any techniques.

If you need more details about my calendar please message and I'll provide full details.

Comment: What's your calendar? Have you checked it's not already implemented in jodatime for example?

Comment: I did check jodatime and ours is not implemented there unfortunately :(
This is a web verison of our calendar: http://www.markinkalpataru.org/MK/assamese_date/assamese_cal.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess parameters M, D and Y are for month, day, year. I also guess you are talking about getting the weekday of the first day of month, right?

I would use the builtin functionality for calendars using the `Calendar` class from [Java SE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

This might look like:

```
...
Calendar localCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
localCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.AUGUST);
localCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
int dayOfWeek = localCalendar.get(Calendar.get(DAY_OF_WEEK));
...
```

You might set additional fields first before, depending on what your needs are of course.

**Edit (regarding the custom type of your calendar):**

You might declare constant arrays with the lengths of the months if there aren't any leap years in your calendar. Then you could manually add up your week days using the modulo operator, like about so:

```
int WEEKDAY_OF_FIRST_DAY_IN_FIRST_YEAR = 3; // 0 for monday, 1 for tuesday, etc.
int LENGTH_OF_WEEK = 7;
int DAYS_IN_YEAR = 365; // 31 + 32 + 31 + 32 + 31 + 30 + 30 + 30 + 29 + 29 + 30 + 30
int DAYS_OF_MONTHS[] = { 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30 };

public static int day(int M, int D, int Y) {
    int firstDayInCurrentYear = WEEKDAY_OF_FIRST_DAY_IN_FIRST_YEAR + 
        (Y * DAYS_IN_YEAR) % LENGTH_OF_WEEK;
    int firstDayOfMonth = firstDayInCurrentYear;

    for (int month = 0; month < M; month++) {
        firstDayOfMonth = 
            (firstDayOfMonth + DAYS_OF_MONTH[month]) % LENGTH_OF_WEEK;
    }

    return firstDayOfMonth;
}
```

**Additional hint:**

This only works if there aren't any leap years in your calendar system!

**Edit:**

Replaced sample number for year length and ellipsis for month length with real numbers

**Edit:**

Added constant for first day in first year (1/1/0).

Comment: Yes, M D and Y are for month, year and date. These are the functions I intend to provide.

However, I can't use the Calendar function because I don't want the day for the default Gregorian calendar. 

I want it for a custom calendar in which there are some months with 32 days and some with 29.

Comment: I think we need more information about the calendar then, with information like "are there leap years?", is there some description of the calendar online?

Comment: Here is an online instance. http://www.markinkalpataru.org/MK/assamese_date/assamese_cal.php

There are 12 months in the calendar with total days in each of them as follows.

Comment: 31 32 31 32 31 30 30 30 29 29 30 30

No leap years.

As of today (08-23-2015), the local date is 5th day of the fifth month of the year 1937.

Our year starts on 14th April. 

Let me know if you need any more info. I appreciate your help.

Comment: This might work with the edit then I think, if you can find out what weekday the first day of the first year (year 0) was. Then you should be able to use the posted function. You should think about zero-based arrays though, weekday 1 will yield result 0 for example. You might just add 1 to fix that.

Comment: Thanks. Will check and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good method and is based on [Zeller's congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence) which you can see for further explanation. However I would go with Java's standard `Calendar` methods as @olik79 has posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32164132/4533527).

Comment: I didn't know about Zeller's congruence yet, thanks for the hint!